# .NET Core exception filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My global exception filter works locally in IISExpress, but `response.WriteAsync()` doesn't seem to work when the application is deployed to production.

Is there a setting in IIS I'm missing?

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    response.ContentType = "application/json";

    string message = context.Exception.Message + (context.Exception.InnerException == null ? "" : " " + context.Exception.InnerException.Message);

    var exObj = new { message = message, stackTrace = context.Exception.StackTrace };

    LogErrorToDatabase(context.Exception);
    response.WriteAsync(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exObj)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Don't think this makes a difference, but the examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling use `await response.WriteAsync(....` not `ConfigureAwait`.

Comment: @TylerJennings no you are correct, they're not awaiting the task they need to run it sync, or await the task

Comment: @JamesBecket Does that resolve your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to await the asynchronous method. It works locally because you have a race condition, a write to the response vs returning the response.

You should implement an async [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which will allow you to await the result of the asynchronous call and avoid the race conditions:

```
public async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
{
    //...
    await response.WriteAsync(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exObj))
}
```

Comment: @mason .Result shouldn't cause deadlocks in .Net-Core see the link to SynchronizationContext

Comment: @Mason but thanks for the link I'll update my answer for async filters

Comment: @mason,  I've updated my answer to use the link you've shown, If you wan't I'll remove the sync option too, can you please remove your downvote